# Unused CSS in Wordpress Plugins

Tags: css

I have been removing Unused css from my wordpress site manually for the past couple hours and had a thought:

Is removing unused CSS from plugins, such as: "wp-content/plugins/woo-variation-swatches/assets/css/frontend-tooltip.min.css" redundant as the original css will be returned upon updating that plugin?

Comment: Yes. Don't edit files from plugins or core ( wp-admin and wp-includes ). They will be overwritten upon updating. In theory most CSS files shouldn't be enqueued unless they're used in some way. Additionally, removing CSS such as this likely (in most cases) won't give your page a noticeable speed boost if that is the goal.

Comment: Thank you for this response and is exactly what I assumed. However I would argue that removing unused css from main theme files can save over 2 seconds of site speed in some cases

Comment: It would be better to either choose a different theme, or build a child theme that only includes the parts you want. That way you can update the parent theme without the stripped-out CSS returning.

Comment: (You can also dequeue plugin CSS.)